# sharepoint rest api url not working when "&" is used in the filter query

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

sharepoint rest api with filter query involving '&' text throws 400 error while executing the get query

example of the query

```
https://test.xx.com/sites/talent/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Function and Eng Name')/items?$select=funcname,Title&$filter=funcname eq 'D&I'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use encodeURI(`funcname eq 'D&I'`) when using rest call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use encodeURIComponent().
In your code use it like this:

```
"https://test.xx.com/sites/talent/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Function and Eng Name')/items?$select=funcname,Title&$filter=funcname eq '" + encodeURIComponent("D&I") + "'"
```

If you want to try it in browser, just replace `&` with `%26` and hit the url.
While using in code, you must **always use** `encodeURIComponent()`